# Pipes inside of sed

Tags: bash, sed

Is there a way to send the back references of the SED s/// command to pipes? In order to get an entry from the text, change it, and then write it back. I found that a substitution inside of SED works:

```
$ echo 'Test ....' | sed 's/Test/'$( echo "<\0>" )'/' 
<Test> ....
```

But the first pipe does not:

```
$ echo 'Test ....' | sed 's/Test/'$( echo "<\0>" | tr 's' 'x' )'/' 
<Test> ....
```

What is the reason? Additionally, I can't understand why this works at all. I thought that $() substitution should be processed before sed (all the more as I broke the quotes).

And how can I insert one s/// command into another using sed? I use bash.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve the effect you're after with GNU sed and the `e` flag:

```
echo 'Test ....' | sed 's/Test.*/echo "<\0>" | tr s x/e'
```

Output:

```
<Text ....>
```

Comment: This is in fact the best answer.

Answer (score 4):

The `tr` command is operating on the text "<\0>", not on "<Test>". The back reference isn't expanded in `sed` until after the pipeline completes. Your second example is equivalent to

```
foo=$( echo "<\0>" | tr 's' 'x' )
echo 'Test ....' | sed 's/Test/'$foo'/'
```

It's a little easier to see here that `tr` has no way of seeing "Test" in its input.